Automating js files to encrypt a value with python and requests-html
Page B(2nd page) request depending on Page (1st page) click which trigger an event in another js files to encrypt a value. How to automate this with Python and requests/requests-html?
E.g. the content is not existed elsewhere or cookies and it was generated by a js when people click on a button. And it will pass as request when opening the next page visiting.
Request
I'm implementing an API call to a website and Selenium will not be an option.

Why is Selenium not an option, if requests-html is?  Both of them use a Chrome browser instance to execute the Javascript.

Firstly, the Selenium is really slow. secondly, there will be other api calls before and after which if Selenium is used... I'll have to due with switching the session between api and browser which I'm not sure if it is possible

the function to be involved is in chunk-vendors.js
